# SDL2 image scaling with anti-aliasing

Tags: c, image, image-processing, sdl

So I wrote this program that I use to display images using SDL2. Honestly, I ported it from SDL1 to SDL2 years ago. I still use this program, but I have noticed that scaling images results in quite horrible aliasing. I'm using SDL2_gfx rotozoom to scale images and I have enabled the smoothing flag, and I have also tried it without the smoothing and it actually looks exactly the same, so I'm thinking it is not working. I have read various posts on here and elsewhere on the internet about porting to SDL2, but this program is somewhat harder to port at least for me. I have tried converting this to the new renderer model, but there is no obvious way to render things at different locations. Oh and the main reason I still use this program is because I use SDL_threads to pre-load the next image, which is extremely useful IMO.

So basically what I want is a way to smooth scale the image before displaying it, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have updated the program to use textures, but the image quality when scaling is still horrible... please help.

This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <dirent.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_thread.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL2_rotozoom.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>

#define MAX_BUF 256

#define FPS_LIMIT 10 // in FPS
#define FPS_DELAY 1000/FPS_LIMIT // in ms

#define ZOOM_LIMIT 10
#define ZOOM(sw,iw) (((double) (sw) / (iw)) > ZOOM_LIMIT ? ZOOM_LIMIT : ((double) (sw) / (iw)))

static SDL_Window * window;
static SDL_Renderer * renderer;
static SDL_Texture * next_texture;
static SDL_DisplayMode dmode;
static SDL_Rect source_rect;

int load_next_image (void * data)
{
    char * name = (char *) data;
    SDL_Surface * temp = IMG_Load (name); // unfree
    if (NULL == temp)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to load image %s\n", name);
        return 1;
    }

    source_rect.w = temp->w;
    source_rect.h = temp->h;
    next_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, temp); // unfree
    SDL_FreeSurface (temp); // free
    if (NULL == next_texture)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to convert image %s\n", name);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void draw_image (SDL_Texture * texture, SDL_Rect * dest, double zoom)
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_Rect temp;
    temp.x = dest->x;
    temp.y = dest->y;
    temp.w = dest->w * zoom;
    temp.h = dest->h * zoom;
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, texture, NULL, &temp, 0.0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface (window);
}

int selector (const struct dirent * dir)
{
    if (0 == strcmp (".", dir->d_name) || 0 == strcmp ("..", dir->d_name)) // add more as needed
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // check arg
    if (2 != argc)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s /path/to/file.jpg\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // get file and directory names
    struct dirent ** dir;
    char dir_name[MAX_BUF];
    char * first_file = strrchr (argv[1], '/') + 1;
    unsigned int length = strlen (argv[1]) - strlen (first_file);
    strncpy (dir_name, argv[1], length);
    dir_name[length] = 0;
    int num_files = scandir (dir_name, &dir, selector, alphasort); // unfree
    if (num_files < 1)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open directory %s\n", dir_name);
        return 1;
    }
    // find first file index
    int i;
    int first_index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
    {
        if (0 == strcmp (first_file, dir[i]->d_name))
        {
            first_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // init SDL
    if (0 != SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    // Settings
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 16);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);

    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    // create window and renderer
    SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode (0, &dmode);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow (first_file, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, dmode.w, dmode.h, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL); // unfree
    if (NULL == window)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED); //unfree
    if (NULL == renderer)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot create renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // load current image
    SDL_Texture * current_texture = NULL;
    int status = load_next_image (argv[1]); // unfree unfree
    SDL_Rect current_rect;
    if (0 == status)
    {
        current_texture = next_texture;
        current_rect = source_rect;
    }
    double zoom = 1.0;
    int prev_x = 0;
    int prev_y = 0;
    int x[2] = {};
    int y[2] = {};
    unsigned int wide = 0;

    // file list loop
    for (i = first_index + 1; i <= num_files + first_index; i++)
    {
        // preload next image if not last
        SDL_Thread * thread = NULL;
        if (i != num_files + first_index)
        {
            strcat (dir_name, dir[i % num_files]->d_name);
            thread = SDL_CreateThread (load_next_image, "lnit", dir_name); // unfree unfree
        }
        // handle current image
        if (0 == status)
        {
            if (current_rect.w > current_rect.h)
            {
                wide = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                wide = 0;
            }
            current_rect.x = x[wide];
            current_rect.y = y[wide];
            draw_image (current_texture, &current_rect, zoom);

            unsigned int go = 1;
            // input loop
            while (1 == go)
            {
                unsigned int frame_limit = SDL_GetTicks() + FPS_DELAY;

                SDL_Event event;
                while (SDL_PollEvent (&event))
                {
                    switch (event.type)
                    {
                        case SDL_QUIT:
                            go = 0;
                            i = num_files + first_index;
                        break;

                        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                            go = 0;
                            if (SDLK_ESCAPE == event.key.keysym.sym)
                            {
                                i = num_files + first_index;
                            }
                        break;

                        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                            switch (event.button.button)
                            {
                                case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT:
                                    prev_x = event.button.x;
                                    prev_y = event.button.y;
                                break;

                                case SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT:
                                    if (1.0 == zoom)
                                    {
                                        zoom = ZOOM(dmode.w, current_rect.w);
                                        x[wide] = (dmode.w / 2) - ((event.button.x - x[wide]) * zoom);
                                        y[wide] = (dmode.h / 2) - ((event.button.y - y[wide]) * zoom);
                                        current_rect.x = x[wide];
                                        current_rect.y = y[wide];
                                        draw_image (current_texture, &current_rect, zoom);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        x[wide] = (dmode.w / 2) - ((event.button.x - x[wide]) / zoom);
                                        y[wide] = (dmode.h / 2) - ((event.button.y - y[wide]) / zoom);
                                        zoom = 1.0;
                                        current_rect.x = x[wide];
                                        current_rect.y = y[wide];
                                        draw_image (current_texture, &current_rect, zoom);
                                    }
                                break;
                            }
                        break;

                        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                            if (SDL_BUTTON_LEFT == event.button.button)
                            {
                                x[wide] += event.button.x - prev_x;
                                y[wide] += event.button.y - prev_y;
                                current_rect.x = x[wide];
                                current_rect.y = y[wide];
                                draw_image (current_texture, &current_rect, zoom);
                            }
                        break;

                        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                            if (SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED == event.window.event)
                            {
                                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface (window);
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // delay
                unsigned int ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
                if (frame_limit < ticks)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (frame_limit > ticks + FPS_DELAY)
                {
                    SDL_Delay (FPS_DELAY);
                }
                else
                {
                    SDL_Delay (frame_limit - ticks);
                }
            }
            SDL_DestroyTexture (current_texture); // free
        }
        // switch to next image if not last
        if (i != num_files + first_index)
        {
            SDL_WaitThread (thread, &status);
            dir_name[length] = 0;
            if (0 == status)
            {
                SDL_SetWindowTitle (window, dir[i % num_files]->d_name);
                current_texture = next_texture;
                current_rect = source_rect;
            }
        }
    }
    // free next image if not last
    if (0 == status && i != num_files + first_index + 1)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture (current_texture); // free
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow (window); // free
    SDL_DestroyRenderer (renderer); // free
    SDL_Quit();
    free (dir); // free
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "no obvious way to render things at different locations"  `SDL_RenderCopyEx()`'s `dstrect` argument?

Comment: Thank you genpfault, that was very useful, I have fixed the code to use rendering, however, the image quality is the same. I have updated the code above. Thanks again for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out. If the zoom is less than 1.0 you should be using shrinkSurface() not rotozoomSurface(), because that is what is actually causing the problem. shrinkSurface() uses an averaging method to shrink the image, whereas rotozoomSurface() uses linear interpolation. It required some more digging, but I'm glad I figured it out. Thanks again.

```
int load_next_image (void * data)
{
    char * name = (char *) data;
    SDL_Surface * temp = IMG_Load (name); // unfree
    if (NULL == temp)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to load image %s\n", name);
        return 1;
    }

    next_image = SDL_ConvertSurface (temp, screen->format, 0); // unfree
    SDL_FreeSurface (temp); // free
    if (NULL == next_image)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to convert image %s\n", name);
        return 1;
    }

    double zoom = ZOOM(dmode.w, next_image->w);
    if (zoom < 1)
    {
        next_zoomed = shrinkSurface (next_image, next_image->w / dmode.w , next_image->w / dmode.w); // unfree
    }
    else if (zoom > 1)
    {
        next_zoomed = rotozoomSurface (next_image, 0.0, zoom, SMOOTHING_ON); // unfree
    }
    else
    {
        next_zoomed = next_image;
    }
    if (NULL == next_zoomed)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to zoom image %s\n", name);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```